# Letras del abecedario en un string

Tags: javascript

Quiero verificar que la cadena de texto tenga todas las letras del abecedario, uso include, peo aunque el string no tenga todas las letras del abecedario me da true.

```
const letter = 'De la a a la z, nos faltan letras';

 function pangram() {

 const newLetter = letter.toLowerCase() 


if(newLetter.includes('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l', 'ñ','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')){
  return true
} else {
   return false
}

}

pangram()
```

Comment: Hola Graziel, bienvenido a SOes. Ésta es una buena primera pregunta: has expuesto el escenario que quieres conseguir, y has añadido el código necesario, siguiendo las reglas de [ask]. Aun así permíteme que te recomiende completar el [tour] para conseguir tu primera medalla y conocer un poco más esta comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `includes` solo toma un valor.

Yo soy fanático de la programación funcional en JS así que esta es mi solución preferida:

```
const letter = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog + ñ';

function pangram() {
    const newLetter = letter.toLowerCase() 
    return !(
        ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','ñ','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
        .map(letra => newLetter.includes(letra))
        .includes(false)
    )
}

console.log(pangram()) // Retorna true
```

Partimos con un arreglo que incluye todas las letras y utilizando map lo convertimos a un arreglo de booleanos donde cada valor es true si la letra está en contenida en la frase original.

Y por último comprobamos que este nuevo arreglo no contenga false (por eso la negación antes del parentesis), lo cual implica que efectivamente la frase contiene todas las letras.

Pregúntame si algo no quedó claro.

Comment: Me gusto esta forma con el metodo map, gracias

Answer (score 3):

Buen día,

Una respuesta alternativa sin utilizar `map` y únicamente con `includes` y `every`

Con `every` puedes iterar dentro del arreglo de tus letras y evaluar una por una si está incluida en el `string` que deseas evaluar

El arreglo con todas las letras lo declaré aparte para que el código fuera más legible

Por cierto, creo que es mejor que tu función tenga un argumento, así puede recibir cualquier texto como entrada y evaluar si tiene todas las letras deseadas o no, por eso declaré `texto` como argumento de la función

```js
const letter = 'De la a 8 a la z, nos faltan letras';
const prueba = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog + ñ'

//Creamos un arreglo con todas las letras para que sea más legible el código
const letras = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l', 'ñ','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

function pangram(texto) {
    const newLetter = texto.toLowerCase();
  return letras.every(letra => newLetter.includes(letra))
}

console.log(pangram(letter)) // Devuelve false
console.log(pangram(prueba)) // Devuelve true
```

Comment: No conocía el `every`. Esta respuesta es mucho mejor.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, tampoco conocia el every